# Firebase (Swift) Reorder Table

Tags: firebase, swift2, firebase-realtime-database

I have a tableview parsed from firebase-data like so:

```
for snap in snapshotSetlists {
    if let songsDict = snap.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
        let key = snap.key
        let song = SongModel(songKey: key, dictionary: songsDict)
        self.songData.append(song)
    }
}
```

How do I manage to enable permanent reordering of the table with

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, moveRowAtIndexPath sourceIndexPath: NSIndexPath, toIndexPath destinationIndexPath: NSIndexPath) {
```

I know that sorting by child is possible, but I cannot figure out how to update an index after reordering the table locally.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I see you haven't gotten an answer to this - I'm dealing with the same thing myself, and I think what I'm doing will be your only option as well.

You need to first make sure that the source query is ordered on a field, not the default which is by key. It is harder to change keys than fields, and probably not what you want to do anyway. In our app, we added a "weight" field to each record, and `queryOrderedByChild` on that. Any sort key field will do.

Once you have this done, re-ordering is now possible, and follows the same technique used by most other iOS cases. There are several ways to do this, but if you don't have a huge data set, the way I found easiest was to make a mutable array copy of the data set. If you use `FirebaseUI` and `FUIArray` for your table, this is easy - just call `[array items]` which will make that copy for you.

From there, use the standard iOS array reordering calls to move the items in the array, then recalculate the sort key for each item. Finally, set the adjusted sorted keys into Firebase. Rough pseudo-code:

```
// Make a temp array to do the move in
NSMutableArray *temp = [[myData items] mutableCopy];
[temp removeObjectAtIndex:sourceIndexPath.row];
[temp insertObject:interest atIndex:destinationIndexPath.row];

// Renumber the items in Firebase
NSInteger sortKey = 0;
for (FIRDataSnapshot *entry in temp) {
    [[entry.ref child:@"mySortKey"] setValue:@(sortKey)];
    sortKey++;
}
```

Depending on how you wired your table to Firebase, it should update automatically at this point.